# How to use regex to replace newlines in HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing, newline

How can I use `RegExp` to replace each individual `\n` character between `<code>` `</code>` tags?

The code below is taking my question too literally. It matches the `\n` in `<code></code>\n<code></code>` because it's technically between an opening and closing `<code>` tag.

```js
const string = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<code>function foo() {

console.log('Hello');

}</code>
<code>function bar() {

console.log('World!');

}</code>
</pre>
</body>
</html>`;

const regExp = /(?<=<code>.*)\n(?=.*<\/code>)/gs;
const newString = string.replace(regExp, '<br>');

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: what about this way: `str.split("\n")` then filter out empty string (after `String.trim()`), finally `Array.join('\n')`

Comment: Are you doing this in the browser as part of the page that was loaded?

Comment: `(?<=<code>.*)` This is a variable width look behind assertion. When you are downstream of any single code tag, this will always match. I'm sure you didn't mean to cite this did you ?

Comment: Since JS does not support the `\G` construct, you can only do this by matching the entire segment between open and close tag, then in a callback, substitute the inner newlines then replace back the entire code segment. Does this sound like something you can do ?

Comment: I mean you could do it this way `(?<=<code>(?:(?!<\/?code).)*)\n(?=(?:(?!<\/?code).)*<\/code>)` but is very slow.

Comment: This was answered and accepted 4 days ago, Why was it closed as needing _focus_ yesterday ? Was there somehing not understood ?  You better close this one too as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938272/how-to-use-regexp-to-replace-each-newline-between-specific-html-tags because why ?

Comment: They get points for doing stuff I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const string = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<code>function foo() {

console.log('Hello');

}</code>
<code>function bar() {

console.log('World!');

}</code>
</pre>
</body>
</html>`;

const regExp = /(?<=<code>(?:(?!<\/?code).)*)\n(?=(?:(?!<\/?code).)*<\/code>)/gs;;
const newString = string.replace(regExp, '<br>');

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: I had tried something similiar without success; specifically, adding a check to make sure a closing tag didn't come before the last opening tag.  Since I couldn't get to work I thought there was maybe some modifier to make the the capture less greedy, since I see similar uses of `RegExp` in `HTML` tags all the time.  Not sure how they don't encounter the same problem I had here.

Comment: You'll notice its the exact same regex in the assertions except the look behind has the constant it checks for first `<code>`. In variable width lookbehinds the regex is processed _RIGHT to LEFT_ as opposed to left to right with _ALL_ other constructs. So the trick is to write it with that in mind. However, variable width lookbehinds use heuristics and can be very time consuming.

Comment: Would you like to copy and paste your answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938272/replace-new-lines-in-between-certain-strings

Comment: LOL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938272/replace-new-lines-in-between-certain-strings

Comment: Why the downvote (again) ? State the technical reason downvoter !

Comment: It should be required to explain downvotes.

Comment: Yeah I mean my answers are being graffitied. Like closing this question for lack of _focus_ 7/25 when it was answered and accepted 7/22. Closed so no more answers are accepted, but isn't it too late for that ?